# rc.local doesn't seem to run on first boot

Tags: linux, debian

Got a bit of a weird issue with a Debian template.

I'm running a script called provisioning.sh. 
This script needs to run on first boot once a template is deployed, so I call it in rc.local with...

```
    /var/provision/provisioning.sh
```

When i initially deploy a template, this script is not run, however If i log on as root and then reboot the VM, the script is run at boot as it should be.

This is obviously not ideal as my provisioning script sets up all sort of bits and bobs and brings the VM online on its final publicly accessible IP, all of which should be automated but its currently requiring intervention to log in and reboot.

I am running the same script on both my Ubuntu template and my CentOS template and it works everytime.

Can anyone think of a reason why this script wont run on first boot with Debian?

Cheers :)

Comment: does "this script is not run" mean "this script is not run" or "it doesn't do what I intend it to"? Say, add a line "touch /tmp/foo" to it and see when and whether change date of that file reflects boot time.

Comment: So indeed, you are right. 
/tmp/foo is created so its not a problem with rc.local :(

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so as Bushmills pointed out, the rc.local was infact running. 
In this instance, it seems that prior to capturing my template, my interfaces file was reset and it wasnt bringing eth0 up prior to running rc.local, so my script was aborting - thanks for the steer in the right direction :)

Comment: If the question was the result of a simple typographical error, it can just be deleted. Such questions are unlikely to be helpful to future visitors.